# How to fix brew doctor warnings

Tags: macos, homebrew, brew-doctor

Im new to messing with the Homebrew package manager please help me learn how to fix my warnings I've noticed it causes problems with python. The warnings are below.

> 1)Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
>   directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3-config
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-config
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m-config
>
> 2)Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
>
> Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or
>   a brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can
>   interfere with other software installs.
>
> 3)Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:   nmap
>   subversion

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problems 1 and 2 are related. I am assuming you installed some version of Python beyond the one that comes on your Mac by default. The easiest and likely best way to fix this are the following steps:

1. Delete existing Python
2. Reinstall Python with these steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos
3. Run the command `brew link nmap`

This should fix your issues.